# Sum of values against each item number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have write `sql server query` which give me this result[image: link]

Here you can see `ITEMNO` is repeating ,i want sum of itemno against two columns which are `TOTALQUANTITYUSE` and `TOTALQUANTITYSALE` .
For example i want one entry against each `itemno` e.g ITEMNO 220415 only one time in single row and sum of values against this item number will be display on one row.Hope you understand.

```
SELECT a.ITEMNO,(COUNT(a.ITEMNO)*a.QTY) as 'Total Quantity USE', 
(COUNT(WR.ITEMEMPNO)*WR.QTY) AS 'Total Quantity Sale'
 FROM InvItems a
  inner join WRKTRANS WR ON WR.ITEMEMPNO=a.ITEMNO
  inner join InvHdr HR ON HR.INVTYPE =a.TYPE
  WHERE a.ITEMNO IS NOT NULL AND a.TYPE='3'
  group by a.ITEMNO,WR.QTY,a.QTY
```

Comment: Please don't provide images of data, post it as `text`.

Comment: sorry,how can i copy text from table?

Comment: can you post your desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work (aggregate the records based on itemno and display the sum) -

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT a.ITEMNO,(COUNT(a.ITEMNO)*a.QTY) as 'Total Quantity USE', 
    (COUNT(WR.ITEMEMPNO)*WR.QTY) AS 'Total Quantity Sale'
     FROM InvItems a
      inner join WRKTRANS WR ON WR.ITEMEMPNO=a.ITEMNO
      inner join InvHdr HR ON HR.INVTYPE =a.TYPE
      WHERE a.ITEMNO IS NOT NULL AND a.TYPE='3'
      group by a.ITEMNO,WR.QTY,a.QTY)
    SELECT ITEMNO,SUM([Total Quantity USE]),SUM([Total Quantity Sale])
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY ITEMNO
```

Comment: @Abshishek your answer is correct but if i want to show other values in `select` then i use groupby is mandatory then all records will be repeated again

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ItemNo, SUM([Total Quantity USE]) AS "Total Quantity USE", SUM([Total Quantity Sale]) AS "Total Quantity Sale"
FROM (your_query) AS q
GROUP BY ItemNo
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggragate function

```
    select itemno,sum([Total Quantity USE] totalQty),
   sum( [Total Quantity Sale] ) as TotalSale,
   count(itemno) as total_iteam from yourtable t    
    group by  itemno
```

Comment: Thanks for response,but not working,,i want something else,,for example `ITEMNO 999011 show only one time in row and same as all other items show only one time in row and value against these row will be show in one row by using sum of item no values `

Answer (score 0):

You need to write multiple CTE statement in order to have extra attribute in your SELECT statement. Few addition in @Abhishek code, please check below.

```
  ;WITH CTE_A AS 
  (
    SELECT a.ITEMNO,(COUNT(a.ITEMNO)*a.QTY) as 'Total Quantity USE', 
    (COUNT(WR.ITEMEMPNO)*WR.QTY) AS 'Total Quantity Sale'
     FROM InvItems a
      inner join WRKTRANS WR ON WR.ITEMEMPNO=a.ITEMNO
      inner join InvHdr HR ON HR.INVTYPE =a.TYPE
      WHERE a.ITEMNO IS NOT NULL AND a.TYPE='3'
      group by a.ITEMNO,WR.QTY,a.QTY
  ),

  WITH CTE_B AS
  (
    SELECT ITEMNO,SUM([Total Quantity USE]),SUM([Total Quantity Sale])
    FROM CTE_A
    GROUP BY ITEMNO
  )

  SELECT *
  FROM 
  CTE_B as B
  INNER JOIN
  Original_Table_For_MoreColumn as C on B.ItemNo =C.ItemNO
```